# php replace my tags (as array key) with array value

Tags: php

Sorry, I am confused to create a correct title. This is my problem, I have a TXT file:

```
{{title}}<br />{{content}}
```

And this is the PHP file:
I load file.txt and replace tags {{variable}} with value from $data['variable']

```
$data = array ( 'title' => 'Hello', 'content' => 'WORLD!!');
$file = file_get_contents("file.txt");
$key = array_keys($data);
$value = array_values($data);
$file = str_replace($key, $value, $file);
echo $file;
```

nothing change from file.txt

I have 2 way to solve this by assign array's key in this format

```
'{{variable}}' => 'value'
```

or write

```
str_replace(array('{{','}}'),'',$file)
```

before

```
echo $file;
```

Is there are another way?

thx before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
function bracelize($str) {
   return '{' . $str . '}';
}

$search = array_map('bracelize', $key);
```

Then just use the `$search` array.

If you are using PHP >= 5.3 you can use an anonymous function if you don't want to pollute the namespace:

```
$search = array_map(function($str){ return '{'. $str .'}';}, $key);
```

That being said, if you are planning to use this as an HTML templating system, please don't. PHP itself is a templating engine; why add more overhead?
Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235179/lightweight-php5-based-template-class-system/2235196#2235196).

Comment: PHP is a templating engine, but if you don't trust the template writer, it may very well be necessary to define a simpler template language inside PHP.

Comment: And PHP for templateing isn't really nice to write nor to look at.

Comment: @nick Well, I think it's just fine, but to each his own.

Comment: well, I am thinking just like @NullUserException, php itself is templating engine and I am developing my own simple cms or framework for my team. 
I didnt use any php templating like smarty instead php tags inside html page. 
But I'm also thinking to create a quick replacement system in the html using own tag like that.

Comment: @Vina You should look really into [MVC](http://oreilly.com/php/archive/mvc-intro.html) and write Views in pure PHP. There is also a number of open source MVC frameworks available: [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/), [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/), [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) just to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array ( 'title' => 'Hello', 'content' => 'WORLD!!');
$file = file_get_contents("file.txt");
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $file = str_replace('{{' . $key . '}}', $value);
}
echo $file;
```

though probably this will be slower.

Another version using regex:

```
$file = preg_replace_callback('#\{\{([A-Za-z0-9]+)\}\}#', function($match) use($data) {
    if (isset($data[$match[1]])) {
        return $data[$match[1]];
    }
}, $file);
```

Another (and my preferred version) is to replace all `#{{([A-Za-z0-9)}}#` in the file with `<?php echo isset($data['$1']) ? $data['$1'] : null; ?>`, cache the resulting PHP Code and then execute providing the `$data` array ;)

Comment: Note that the version using regex needs PHP >= 5.3