# How do I install the Twig Template Engine?

Tags: php, twig, mamp, template-engine

I am running Mamp as my local server. I Have installed Twig in `/Applications/MAMP/svn/twig/twig/lib`. I have included this path in my php.ini file:

```
include_path = ".:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php:/Applications/MAMP/svn/zendframework/trunk/library:/Applications/MAMP/svn/twig/twig/lib";
```

What needs to go into my htdocs folder in order for me to complete the installation and access Twig?

Comment: May I ask you why would you use twig when you are already using the Zend framework? I'd suggest you to stay away from PHP templating engines in general. [Here's why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235179/lightweight-php5-based-template-class-system/2235196#2235196).

Comment: I am just doing a tutorial that requires a template engine. Thanks for the info though......

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to install anything, you can just use it in PHP. Here's a simple script to load and render a template:

```
require_once( "Twig/Autoloader.php" );

Twig_Autoloader::register();
// Load template files from the ./tpl/ folder and use ./tpl/cache/ for caching
$twig = new Twig_Environment( new Twig_Loader_Filesystem("./tpl"),
    array( "cache" => "./tpl/cache" ) );

// Load and render 'template.tpl'
$tpl = $twig->loadTemplate( "template.tpl" );
echo $tpl->render( array("msg"=>"Hello, World!") );
```

Your template.tpl could look like this:

```
<html>
    <!-- ... -->
    <body>
        <h1>{{ msg|e }}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

This example will just escape and echo "Hello, World".

For more information just read the documentation for [(PHP) developpers](http://www.twig-project.org/book/03-Twig-for-Developers) and [template designers](http://www.twig-project.org/book/02-Twig-for-Template-Designers).

Answer (score 0):

```
include __DIR__ . "/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php";  

//register autoloader  

Twig_Autoloader::register();  

//loader for template files  

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates');  

//twig instance  

$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('cache' => 'cache'));  

//load template file  

$template = $twig->loadTemplate('index.html');  

//render a template  

echo $template->render(array('title' => 'Welcome to Twig template'));
```

find more info on this [**Tutorial**](http://www.zainabed.com/2014/10/twig-tutorials-install-and-configure.html)