# Print array to template without template engine

Tags: php, templates, arrays

I have a simple associative array in PHP containing data I like to print out in a format specified by a HTML template. The template would look something like this:

```
<html><head>Some header</head>
<body>
<b>{data1}</b>: {data2}

<b>{meta1}</b>: {meta2}

<b>{post1}</b>: {post2}

<i>Note</i>: {data1}, {meta1}, {post1} Some text

{data2}, {meta2} Some text
etc.
</body></html>
```

I wish to avoid using a template engine as much as possible since this is a simple program and I like to keep things simple.

Comment: Well then just use PHP code to echo the correct values from your array. Oh and it would be useful to see the array if you want any constructive help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, I found the answer to my own question. In short, it is, use PHP's:

```
HEREDOC
```

and if I need to run any function within HEREDOC, it's possible too!

Thanks to the answers to these questions:

- [Lightweight PHP5 based template class/system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235179/lightweight-php5-based-template-class-system/2235196#2235196)
- [Calling PHP functions within HEREDOC strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104516/calling-php-functions-within-heredoc-strings)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend something like

```
 $tmpl_output = str_replace(['{{POST1}}','{{META1}}'],[$post1, $meta1],$template);
```

No template engine, very fast mechanism, and you have nice clean tokenization and markup.